# Problem with scaling

Tags: errors

The code below work without `[scale=0.5]`. Any idea how to get it to work with `[scale=0.5]`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you loaded the incorrect package use `graphicx` with an `x` not `s` for the scale= syntax

Answer (score 3):

Use `graphicx` (not `graphics`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

\end{document}
```